# How can i outsource functions that use state and do setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, design-patterns

I have a class which has many functions, i wish to outsource these functions and put each group of function inside a file of their own and then use them by importing and calling them.
Usually this is very simple, you simply put the function bodies inside another file and then export them, but in my case i use `this.state` and `this.setState`, is it still possible to outsource these function? if not, is there a better practice?
Thank you.

Comment: You could pass the class `this.setState.bind(this)` so that the other class can call that function whenever necessary. That function also accepts a function as an argument, which passes you the current state, so your external class could use that callback pattern.

Comment: No, thats not really possible (or at least: it's quite error prone). As of today I wouldn't use classes with React anymore, instead I'd use React hooks ... and they can easily be split up into different files.

Comment: I think if U want to outsource these functions, they should be independent on classes. They should just compute some values (state) from input parameters and return it. Then in your class use returned value to setState.

Answer (score 0):

I just knocked this up real quick with no testing whatsoever, tell me if this is kinda what you were looking for?

```
window._stateManager = new StateManager();

class X extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        _stateManager.addStateFunction(this.setState.bind(this));
    }
}


class StateManager() {
    constructor() {
        this.stateFunctions = [];
    }

    addStateFunction(ss) {
        this.stateFunctions.push(ss);
    }

    updateStates(obj) {
        this.stateFunctions.forEach(ss => {
            ss((state => {
                // here you have access to "this.state" as state
                return Object.assign({}, state, obj);
                // whatever you return from this function changes the state of the react component
            }))
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to update the state by the function that doesn't belong to your component or child component. It doesn't make sense. You want to use redux there will be a single source of state of your entire App stored in the store. All your state update logic will be separated in reducer and you would have access to action creator that can update your App's state.

Comment: Who said it doesn't belong to my component!, i simply said that the component had gotten too big and i wanted to make things simpler by outsourcing the functions, but since lots of them used setState i was a bit unsure of how to processed